# How to wrap multiple middleware functions into one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a number of middleware functions similar to the following:

```
function validate(req, res, next) {
  req.validationError = new Error('invalid');
}

function checkValid(req, res, next) {
  if (req.validationError) {
    next(req.validationError);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

function respond() {
  res.json({result: 'success'});
}
```

Is there a way to wrap them into one function? So I'd do something like:

```
function respondIfValid(req, res, next) {
  // Evoke the following middleware: 

  // validate
  // checkValid
  // respond
}

app.use('/', respondIfValid);
```

Instead of:

```
app.use('/', validate, checkValid, respond);
```

Comment: Is this goal for this middleware to be an atomic unit?  Or another way of asking, what's wrong with just putting all the logic in one function?

Comment: I'm generally curious whether middleware can be used in the above way.

Answer (score 5):

try with following code

```
app.use('/', [validate, checkValid,respond]);
```

***OR***

```
var middleware = [validate, checkValid,respond];

app.use('/', middleware );
```

Need to placed all function in that series as your requirement of execution.

Thanks

Comment: Ideally `middleware` would be a function.

Comment: You can wrap up all function without taking in an array. so we can pass directly.